# Using fineuploader with react-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fine-uploader

I'm trying to use fineuploader with react and have installed all the relevant dependencies. 
Following is the code I use:-

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers'
import Gallery from 'react-fine-uploader'

import 'react-fine-uploader/gallery/gallery.css'

const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
    options: {
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        }
    }
})

class UploadComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Gallery uploader={uploader} />
        )
    }
}

export default UploadComponent
```

But I get the following errors:-

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Gallery`.
at invariant (invariant.js?7313:44)
at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js?e676:74)
at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js?c86a:44)
at eval (ReactChildReconciler.js?c86a:71)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js?5edf:77)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js?5edf:93)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js?5edf:93)
at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js?5edf:172)
at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js?c86a:70)
at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js?e1f8:185)
```

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `Gallery`.
>   in Gallery (created by UploadComponent)
>   in UploadComponent

I've been following the react fineuploader documentation and I've tried a few different things but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is some unmet dependency, which in my case was:

```
react-transition-group@1.x
```

I had

```
react-transition-group@2.x
```

**Removing 2.x and installing 1.2.1 fixed the problem.**

Keep an eye on installation dependencies for any package you are trying to configure.

*Thanks to the react-fine-upload owner [rnicholus](https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader/issues/150#issuecomment-333824444)  for the help.*

Comment: You're a life saver!!! I've been looking all day on the internet for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import `Gallery` component from module.

`import Gallery from 'react-fine-uploader'`

**Update:** 
Also try wraping `Gallery` inside a div

```
class UploadComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Gallery uploader={uploader} />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the complete error stack trace that you are getting now(try by reloading server)?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the server. The only errors I get are in the browser's console.

Comment: And I'm getting the same errors as before. The ones I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is the gallery componenent, if it helps. 
 https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiuVKFBrrB6DtysP8M_BjKPhsLW1

Comment: it is minified version of gallery class. I could see it in their git repo https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader/blob/master/src/gallery/index.jsx. I don't think so something wrong with Gallery component. I think you're missing something while importing.